# Feature enginnering base on previous data for tennis ATP dataset

Tags: python, pandas, feature-engineering

I have a dataset base on results of tennis matches.

I would like add a new feature which indicated the performance of a player based on its last 10 matches ( percentage of winning matches)

Here is an exctrat of my dataset

```
       Date             Winner     Player1         Player2      
0   2000-01-03            1     Ljubicic I.     Dosedel S.         
1   2000-01-03            2     Tarango J.      Kiefer N.         
2   2000-01-03            1     Luxa P.         Gaudio G.          
3   2000-01-03            2     El Aynaoui Y.   Dupuis A.          
4   2000-01-03            2     Cherkasov A.    Arazi H.
```

winner = 1   means player 1 is the winner and
winner = 2   means player 2 is the winner

Here is an exemple of what I expect:

```
       Date             Winner     Player1         Player2      P1_last10     P2_last10
0   2000-01-03            2     Ljubicic I.     Dosedel S.         0.5          0.7
1   2000-01-03            2     Tarango J.      Kiefer N.          0.4          0.5
2   2000-01-03            1     Luxa P.         Gaudio G.          0.7          0.6
3   2000-01-03            2     El Aynaoui Y.   Dupuis A.          0.4          0.4
4   2000-01-03            1     Cherkasov A.    Arazi H.           0.8          0.3
```

P1_last10 et P2_last10 return the ratio of winning matches on last 10 matches for each players

For exemple: P1_last10 =0.7 means player1 has won 7 of its 10 last matches

Do you have an idea how to get such feature please ?